# click event and multiple data object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering how do you get the index of an item that has been click in a collection, e.g a list in `ul li`?

And how do I access that data in the click event that has multiple tabs?

On the click event below, there is a field for data and I want to get that data corresponding to the index of the clicked item.

How do i do that?

```
$(this).find('.tabs .tab').on('click', 'a span', { tab: 'Sale-Items', tab: 'All-Items' }, function (e) {
     alert(e.data.tab[0]); // <-- doesn't work
     $(this).unwrap('<a href="#"></a>').end()
     $(this).parent().siblings().each(function () {
         $(this).find('span:not(a span)').wrap('<a href="#"></a>');
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to tell exactly what you want, but if you want the index number of the `li` in which the element was clicked, do this:

```
var index = $(this).closest('li').index();
```

I have no idea what you're trying to do with:

```
{ tab: 'Sale-Items', tab: 'All-Items' }
```

An object can't have duplicate properties. But you access the data with `event.data.tab`.

Perhaps you meant to use an Array:

```
['Sale-Items', 'All-Items']

event.data[0]
```

Or you could have an object that references your array:

```
{tab:['Sale-Items', 'All-Items']}

event.data.tab[0]
```

Comment: the other part is how do i get the data part { tab: 'Sale-Items', tab: 'All-Items' } in my click function. I've tried e.data.tab[0] and that doesn't work i just get the letter A for All-Items

Comment: an array worked perfectly why didn't I think of that. duh! thatnks dude

Answer (score 0):

If try something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/jlrvpuma/GTZxc/2/